# How do I access production Android logs?

Tags: android, logging, logstash, logcat, android-log

I use Android libraries that have logging statements like the below that I'd like to monitor.

```
import android.util.Log;
...
Log.d(...);
Log.e(...);
```

When I'm in development, I view logs with logcat. Then I publish to the app to the store, and users download and use it. How do I collect all their logs? Is there a library I can install that takes all `Log.*`s from my app and sends it to a service like Logstash, Loggly, Logz, etc?

Comment: While the duplicate question refers to "system classes", the problem is tied to Logcat, not what classes are doing the logging.

Comment: That talks about all logs—do you know if it's possible to just get the ones from my app?

Comment: There is no documented and supported means of doing this. AFAIK, the approach shown in the duplicate *question* (not my answer) will work on some devices to get your own process' log messages. IMHO, for your own logs, use a [logging library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/57?sort=created) that logs to a location you control, rather than screwing around with undocumented/unsupported solutions.